# Cannot retrieve django serialized json using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, django

Hi I am parsing serialzed json -

```
def wall_copy(request):
    posts = user_post.objects.order_by('id')[:20].reverse()
    posts_serialized = serializers.serialize('json', posts)
    return JsonResponse(posts_serialized, safe=False)
```

and trying to get data as-

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
            setInterval(function() 
        {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("GET","http://10.8.21.17:8000/wall/wall_copy/",false);
            xhr.send(null);
            var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            //alert(xhr.status+' '+xhr.statusText);
            for(i=0; i<20; i++)
            {
                alert(data[i].post_content);
            }
                }, 3000);
    });
```

But the problem is that every time it alerts as 'Undefined'. I checked the url and the server is sending json data but I am unable to fetch it.

Json data-

```
"[{\"fields\": {\"post_id\": \"rahularyan06:16PM on February 26, 2015\", \"posted_by\": \"rahularyan\", \"post_content\": \"koi nhi re\", \"time_of_post\": \"2015-02-26T18:16:00Z\"}, \"model\": \"wall.user_post\", \"pk\": 77}, {\"fields\": {\"post_id\": \"aquaman06:00PM on February 26, 2015\", \"posted_by\": \"aquaman\", \"post_content\": \"kuch nhi\", \"time_of_post\": \"2015-02-26T18:00:44Z\"}, \"model\": \"wall.user_post\", \"pk\": 76}, {\"fields\": {\"post_id\": \"rahularyan06:00PM on February 26, 2015\", \"posted_by\": \"rahularyan\", \"post_content\": \"kya hua??\", \"time_of_post\": \"2015-02-26T18:00:04Z\"}, \"model\": \"wall.user_post\", \"pk\": 75}, {\"fields\": {\"post_id\": \"aquaman12:01AM on February 26, 2015\", \"posted_by\": \"aquaman\", \"post_content\": \"lelo\", \"time_of_post\": \"2015-02-26T00:01:14Z\"}, \"model\": \"wall.user_post\", \"pk\": 74}, {\"fields\": {\"post_id\": \"aquaman10:41AM on February 25, 2015\", \"posted_by\": \"aquaman\", \"post_content\": \"sahi me lega??\", \"time_of_post\": \"2015-02-25T10:41:43Z\"}, \"model\": \"wall.user_post\", \"pk\": 73}, {\"fields\": {\"post_id\": \"aquaman10:41AM on February 25, 2015\", \"posted_by\": \"aquaman\", \"post_content\": \"sahi me lega??\", \"time_of_post\": \"2015-02-25T10:41:34Z\"}, \"model\": \"wall.user_post\", \"pk\": 72}, {\"fields\": {\"post_id\": \"shreyansh10:41AM on February 25, 2015\", \"posted_by\": \"shreyansh\", \"post_content\": \"yo\", \"time_of_post\": \"2015-02-25T10:41:17Z\"}, \"model\": \"wall.user_post\", \"pk\": 71}, {\"fields\": {\"post_id\": \"aquaman10:40AM on February 25, 2015\", \"posted_by\": \"aquaman\", \"post_content\": \"muh me lega??\", \"time_of_post\": \"2015-02-25T10:40:53Z\"}, \"model\": \"wall.user_post\", \"pk\": 70}, {\"fields\": {\"post_id\": \"aquaman10:40AM on February 25, 2015\", \"posted_by\": \"aquaman\", \"post_content\": \"bc\", \"time_of_post\": \"2015-02-25T10:40:42Z\"}, \"model\": \"wall.user_post\", \"pk\": 69}, {\"fields\": {\"post_id\": \"shreyansh10:40AM on February 25, 2015\", \"posted_by\": \"shreyansh\", \"post_content\": \"lele\", \"time_of_post\": \"2015-02-25T10:40:28Z\"}, \"model\": \"wall.user_post\", \"pk\": 68}, {\"fields\": {\"post_id\": \"aquaman10:39AM on February 25, 2015\", \"posted_by\": \"aquaman\", \"post_content\": \"kya bhai??\", \"time_of_post\": \"2015-02-25T10:39:39Z\"}, \"model\": \"wall.user_post\", \"pk\": 67}, {\"fields\": {\"post_id\": \"aquaman10:38AM on February 25, 2015\", \"posted_by\": \"aquaman\", \"post_content\": \"sb mast\", \"time_of_post\": \"2015-02-25T10:38:22Z\"}, \"model\": \"wall.user_post\", \"pk\": 66}, {\"fields\": {\"post_id\": \"shreyansh10:38AM on February 25, 2015\", \"posted_by\": \"shreyansh\", \"post_content\": \"or baaki??\", \"time_of_post\": \"2015-02-25T10:38:05Z\"}, \"model\": \"wall.user_post\", \"pk\": 65}, {\"fields\": {\"post_id\": \"aquaman10:03AM on February 25, 2015\", \"posted_by\": \"aquaman\", \"post_content\": \"badiya\", \"time_of_post\": \"2015-02-25T10:03:39Z\"}, \"model\": \"wall.user_post\", \"pk\": 64}, {\"fields\": {\"post_id\": \"shreyansh10:03AM on February 25, 2015\", \"posted_by\": \"shreyansh\", \"post_content\": \"thik ba\", \"time_of_post\": \"2015-02-25T10:03:23Z\"}, \"model\": \"wall.user_post\", \"pk\": 63}, {\"fields\": {\"post_id\": \"aquaman10:00AM on February 25, 2015\", \"posted_by\": \"aquaman\", \"post_content\": \"kaisan??\", \"time_of_post\": \"2015-02-25T10:00:30Z\"}, \"model\": \"wall.user_post\", \"pk\": 62}, {\"fields\": {\"post_id\": \"aquaman10:00AM on February 25, 2015\", \"posted_by\": \"aquaman\", \"post_content\": \"hi\", \"time_of_post\": \"2015-02-25T10:00:04Z\"}, \"model\": \"wall.user_post\", \"pk\": 61}, {\"fields\": {\"post_id\": \"aquaman09:58AM on February 25, 2015\", \"posted_by\": \"aquaman\", \"post_content\": \"abe jldi likh\", \"time_of_post\": \"2015-02-25T09:58:43Z\"}, \"model\": \"wall.user_post\", \"pk\": 60}, {\"fields\": {\"post_id\": \"aquaman09:57AM on February 25, 2015\", \"posted_by\": \"aquaman\", \"post_content\": \"hello\", \"time_of_post\": \"2015-02-25T09:57:49Z\"}, \"model\": \"wall.user_post\", \"pk\": 59}, {\"fields\": {\"post_id\": \"shreyansh09:39AM on February 25, 2015\", \"posted_by\": \"shreyansh\", \"post_content\": \"lele\", \"time_of_post\": \"2015-02-25T09:39:39Z\"}, \"model\": \"wall.user_post\", \"pk\": 58}]"
```

Help me how can I get this data through javascript.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you see when you dump out the whole `data` structure to the console? `console.log(data)`?

Comment: It is displaying the json data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should access this way the json response in javascript:

```
data[i].fields.post_content
```

The serializer creates for each object a dictionary with keys

- `fields`, which is the values for each field
- `model`, which is the model name which in your case is `"wall.user_post"`.
- `pk`, which is the primary key of your object.

Also in your view you convert to json twice. One time with the serializer and one time with the `JsonResponse`. You should return the following value from your view:

```
return HttpResponse(posts_serialized, content_type="application/json")
```

Comment: I have already tried it but it is giving error that 'data[i].fields is not defined'

Comment: in `alert(data)` it is displaying the json but in `alert(data[0])` it is displaying '['...why is that..??

Comment: I tried `alert(data[0][0].fields.post_content)` but it is giving error - `TypeError: data[0][0].fields is undefined`

Comment: No, again it is just giving `]`

Comment: Yes this is the exact code that I wrote in my views.py

Comment: Well I checked and it is actually not a json but a string..but what did I do wrong..??

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I managed a simple JSON example:

```
def search(request):
    rows = MyDBObject.objects.all()
    response = {}
    for row in rows:
        response[row .id] = {'name': row.name, 'field1': row.field1, 'field2': row.field2}
    return JsonResponse(response)
```

In javascript:

```
$.getJSON('/ajax/search', function(data) {
  var items = [];

  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    items.push('<li id="' + key + '"><a href="' + val['field2'] + '" data-ajax="false">' + val['field1'] + ' by ' + val['field2'] + '</a></li>');
  });

  $('<ul/>', {
    'class': 'my-new-list',
    html: items.join('')
  }).appendTo('#search_results_list');
});
```